# Vue - passing v-for index from parent to child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I've done the research but can't find a good answer.  My parent and child component code is below.  How do I pass the index for the v-for loop in the parent to the child component for use there?  I want to hide any of the gauges past #4 for mobile screens, but show all of them on a desktop.

Parent:

```js
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <data-block 
            v-for="(gauge, index) in device.gauges" 
            :metric="gauge.metric" 
            :value="gauge.value" 
            :unit="gauge.unit" 
            :alarm="gauge.alarm" 
            :idx="index">
        </data-block>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child:

```js
app.component('data-block', {
    props: ['alarm', 'metric','value','unit','idx'],
    template: `<div v-bind:class="'col card px-0 text-center border' + ((alarm) ? ' border-danger':' border-success') + ((idx > 3) ? ' d-none d-md-block':'')">\
    <div class="card-header p-1">{{metric}}</div>\
        <div class="card-body p-1 align-middle">\
            <h1 class=" text-center display-1 font-weight-normal text-nowrap">{{value}}</h1>\
        </div>\
    <div class="card-footer p-1">{{unit}}</div>\
</div>`,
    created: ()=> console.log(this.idx)  //yields "undefined"
})
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging in the `mounted` hook?

Comment: Do you get any errors with it? `this` shouldn't be correct inside an arrow function

Comment: You're right about the arrow - I had forgotten about that.  I did try it in the mounted hook first and didn't get anything there but I was changing a lot of variables trying to get it to work at the time and may have overlooked something.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `idx` prop correctly, but Instead of checking its value inside `created` hook, try displaying it in the `template` instead, to make sure it's not an issue with timing (it might not be defined when the child component is created):

```html
<div>{{idx}}</div>
```

Also, to make the code easier to read and write, I would suggest you to move the static classes to `class` attribute and the dynamic classes to `v-bind:class` attribute, and also make it multiline:

```js
template: `
 <div 
   class="col card px-0 text-center border"
   :class="{
     'd-none d-md-block': idx > 3,
     'border-danger': alarm,
     'border-success': !alarm
   }"
 >
 ...
`
```

Comment: Hmm - I haven't seen that v-bind thing done before but I'm new to this.  The ":" are obviously conditionals.  I appreciate the advice.